# wordpress extract media url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, media

```
 $path = parse_url($post->guid, PHP_URL_PATH);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($path);
       echo "<br>";
```

here i get

/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/kl-2-256.png

/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bg-eBook.pdf

here i want to remove /wp-conent/uploads from these paths and extract only year month and image name

i tried with

```
  $segments = explode('/', rtrim($path, '/'));
```

but not working properly every time

is there any proper and best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `list()` construct to map the three data you need. The code is exploding the path by `/` and then looks from behind and passes those values to your mapped variables of `list`.

```
$path = '/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/kl-2-256.png';
list($year,$month,$image)=array_slice(explode('/',$path),-3,3);
```

You can then print `$year,$month and $image` separately.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
$path = parse_url($post->guid, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = str_replace("wp-content/uploads/", "", $path);

echo $path;
```